# getResourceAsStream returns null?

Tags: java, eclipse, null, resources

I saw same posts like this but any of them could resolve my problem. I have my environment.properties which i want to access by:

```
InputStream inputStream = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/support/environment.properties");
```

inputStream is always receiving null. This is my project structure

```
MyProject
->src
-->test
--->java
---->com.desp.automation.config (package)
----->CrossAutomationConfigTest
-->main
--->resources
---->support
----->environment.properties
```

Do you know what's happening ? I would appreciate your help. Regards

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This happens to me all the time! The actual path to the resource depends on the class loader meaning it depends on whether you are running in pure java, or a web container. I usually nail it by playing with the path to find it...things to try:

(1) /resoures/support/...
(2) / main/resources/support/...
(3) the above without a leading /

I think the requirement for the leading / depends on whether you are calling getResourceAsStream from a static or non-static method and whether the resources are packaged in an archive (zip/jar/war) or whether the app is unarchived into files in the deployment environment.

To avoid deployment issues, I write some code to 'discover' the path by trying getResourceAsStream until a non-null inputStream is returned.

Comment: I tried every possible location but i can't find it! How could you discover these path? Another thing, i saw at another posts that this could be a java build path problem, do you think that these could be related to this case?

Comment: /main/resources/support/environment.properties works for me (in Eclipse).

Comment: I tried with:       System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/main/resources/support/environment.properties"));
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/main/resources/support/environment.properties"));
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/support/environment.properties"));
        System.out.println(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/support/environment.properties"));

i don't know what else could be.. So annoying

Comment: Maybe your eclipse setup. I see src (folder) followed by main.resources.support (package) and then environment.properties (file)

Comment: And I see, src (folder) followed by test.java.com.desp.automation (package) followed by Config.java (file). So, both packages have src (folder) as a common root. I bet, instead of packages your test/java are folders and so the root for the com.desp.automation package is actually test/java instead of src. If that's the case, you'd need to create a helper class in main.resources.support to access the properties from test.

Comment: i solved it creating new project ahah. Thank you anyway!

Comment: [Class.getResourceAsStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) has consistent, predictable, strictly specified behavior.  The only reason to be "playing with the path" is a misunderstanding of how that method works.  The original question's code is correct;  most likely the project's packaging settings were the problem.

Comment: Yup, that's where we ended up after trying a few things.

Comment: @VGR, Could you please elaborate more on that?

Comment: Since I don't use Eclipse, I can't describe exactly how to do the packaging.  Every .jar file is actually a .zip file.  getResourceAsStream looks in every .jar file on the classpath (which is often just the one .jar file containing your application) for a jar entry (zip entry) matching the requested path (which must not start with "/", as the docs to which I've linked explain).  In the case of the original question, src/main/resources needs to be packaged in the .jar file.  Most Java IDEs have a "packaging" section in a project's "properties" window.